# Multipart messages like in zmq in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, zeromq

Is there a option in RabbitMQ to send multipart messages?

> This fact allows for using multi-part messages for adding
>   coarse-grained structure to your message. The example with two
>   matrices illustrates the point. You send the two matrices as two
>   message parts and thus avoid the copy. However, at the same time the
>   matrices are cleanly separated, each residing in its own message part
>   and you are guaranteed that the separation will be preserved even on
>   the receiving side. Consequently you don't have to put matrix size
>   into the message or invent any kind of "matrix delimiters".

Comment: What do you mean? Multiparty as to RFC 1341?

Comment: I don't have time to read full RFC 1341.
ZMQ developers described what they are calling "multipart" in here
http://zeromq.org/blog:zero-copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature like [multipart content](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) publish in [AMQP protocol](http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf) (see section 2.1.2 Message Flow) at all.

Multipart message sending and receiving can be implemented on application level, but there are no known use cases for it.